# Keep a Numbers chart stationary while scrolling the page?

Tags: numbers, iwork, macos

In Numbers, is there a way to make a chart stay visible at the top of the page while I scroll down through the rest of the page's contents? Similar to how a table's header row can be made to stay visible at the top when scrolling through the table?

I have a simple chart derived from a table with several hundred rows. To add new data I have to scroll all the way to the end of the table, but then to see the new data in the chart I have to scroll all the way back up to the top of the page. It's only a minor but hassle, but my gut tells me it must be avoidable somehow.

Comment: Consider putting the chart and summary data on a separate sheet - I find it gives me more layout flexibility and the data has suitable column widths...